# Ubuntu 22.04, only display side-bar when activities button clicked/windows key pressed

Tags: mouse, ubuntu-gnome

I'm struggling to figure out how/if-it-is-possible to disable the side-bar appearing in ubuntu if my *mouse ventures to the left-most edge* of the screen. I still want to be able to view the side bar in the overview display (ie. if I click the activities button or windows key) I just don't want it to turn up when my mouse hits the edge. I've tried various extensions but can't seem to find anything that fits the bill. Am I missing an obvious plugin or does no such feature currently exist?

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, but thanks for the -1 in all-of-a-day when it is abundantly obvious that LTS is the predominant flavour.  Real friendly.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you meant could be the classic always auto-hide behavior, which can be achieved via the steps below:

1. First, search for and install `Dconf Editor` from Ubuntu Software App.
2. Launch `Dconf Editor` and navigate to `org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock`.
3. Finally, scroll down and use ON/OFF switches to do following changes: disable `intellihide`, disable `dock-fixed`, and enable `auto-hide`.

After that, the dock bar should always hide and only visible when mouse hitting screen edge or trigger overview.

For the previous changes, there are also a few commands can do the same things:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide false`

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-fixed false`

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide true`

via: https://fostips.com/auto-hide-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

It appears you would rather prefer the default behaviour of Gnome Shell where the dock is only available in the Activities overview.

To achieve this, disable the Gnome Shell extension "Ubuntu Dock", which is used by Ubuntu to have a Dock on the desktop.

- Install `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` if you do not have it already
- Load the "Extensions" tool
- Turn off "Ubuntu Dock" under the section "Build-in".

You can also use Extensions Manager instead.

Answer (score 0):

With a little tweak of this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1432495/862074), you can always hide the sidebar on the left except when you click the activities button or press the windows key :

1. Search and install Dconf Editor from Ubuntu Software App.
2. Launch Dconf Editor and navigate to org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock.
3. disable intellihide
4. disable dock-fixed
5. disable auto-hide